# Area between $y=e^{-x}$ and $y=e^{-x}\sin x$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Let $x_n$ denote the $x$-coordinate of the $n$th point of contact between the curves $y=e^{-x}$ and $y=e^{-x}\sin x$, with $0<x_1<x_2<\cdots$, and let $A_n$ denote the area of the region enclosed by the two curves between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\pi/2}.$$

**My attempt:**

The two curves meet at $\sin x= 1 \iff x=\pi/2 + 2\pi n,~n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $$x_n=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}$$and $$x_{n+1}=x_n+2\pi.$$Now $e^{-x}\geqslant e^{-x}\sin x$ since $\sin x\leqslant 1$ by definition. So we have, $$A_n=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}\left(e^{-x}-e^{-x}\sin x\right)~\mathrm{d}x=-e^{-x}\bigg|_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}-I,$$where $$I=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}e^{-x}\sin x~\mathrm{d}x=-e^{-x}\sin x\bigg|_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}+\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}e^{-x}\cos x~\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=-e^{-x}\sin x\bigg|_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}-e^{-x}\cos x\bigg|_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}-I$$$$\Longrightarrow I=-\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-x}\sin x\bigg|_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}+e^{-x}\cos x\bigg|_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}\right].$$It is clear that $\cos x_{n+1}=\cos x_n = 0$ and that $\sin x_{n+1}=\sin x_n = 1$ and so we have $$A_n=-e^{-x_{n+1}}+e^{-x_n}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x_n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-x_n}-e^{-x_{n+1}}\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x_n}(1-e^{-2\pi}).$$
Now for the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2\pi})\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-x_n}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\pi/2}(1-e^{-2\pi})\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2\pi n }$$$$=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\pi/2}(1-e^{-2\pi})\cdot \frac{e^{-2\pi}}{1-e^{-2\pi}}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-5\pi/2},$$which is not what I had to show.

---

So, can anybody point out exactly where my working went wrong? A friend suggested that using $$x_n=\frac{(4n-3)\pi}{2}$$ instead of $$x_n=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}$$ and following the same procedure I followed yields the required result. But I cannot see the difference between choosing either of the two as $x_n$. Shouldn't both give the same result anyway?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem asks you to consider the $n$th crossing of those two greater than zero, starting at the first crossing. Quite simply, the first formula you used starts at $5\pi/2$, while the one your friend suggested starts at $\pi/2$. You simply missed the first few terms in the series when you started summing from $5\pi/2$ !

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be overly complicating it. Note that $e^{-x}\geq e^{-x}\sin(x)$ for all $x$.  Thus, the answer is simply

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\infty} e^{-x}(1-\sin(x)) \, dx = \frac{e^{-\pi /2}}{2}.$$

It appears that you already know how to evaluate the relevant anti-derivatives.